Синонимизация меток [nextjs] и [next]
Синонимизировать:
nextjs  - 290 вопрос, описание есть
next - 25 вопроса, описания нет
Основная метка - nextjs
Потому что:

Все вопросы с меткой next в равной степени относятся и к nextjs
На https://stackoverflow.com/ метки next не существует, значит даже при большем количестве вопросов в ней не возникло необходимости

Поправка: метка может использоваться для итераторов, хотя для них есть итераторы - возможно лучше для итераторов переназначить вручную, остальное объединить c nextjs, а саму метку next удалить и запретить.

[tag:next] использовали в вопросах про итераторы: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1487010/532877 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1461479/532877 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1387457/532877 4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1379267/532877

@Зонтик Ассоциации понятные, но, по-моему, проще и понятнее такие случаи заменить на метку итераторы, иначе найти эти самые итераторы по метке next среди фронтендских как иголку в стоге сена. Или как вариант - где можно заменить на итераторы, остальные объединить с nextjs и удалить и запретить метку.

Да, совершенно верно. Я про то, что прежде чем синонимизировать, нужно почистить метку от итераторов и прочей бурды, которая не связана с next.js

На еn.so next.js с точкой. Мы не хотим так же? Хотя, вот недавно объединили именно в сторону без точки.

По-новому next можно будет присвоить? По-моему, по возможности желательно запретить. Хотя в основном ее использовали фронтендеры, им отдавать в качестве синонима нельзя - может и другим подходить. А в итоге опять через некоторое время придется переприсваивать и объединять.

Запрещать метку могут только сотрудники, а эта процедура уж очень сильно может затянуться. Пока проще подчищать иногда, если что.

Объединил метку next с nextjs (без синонимизации):
updating post history, 18 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 18 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 8 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'next': [next] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 297
tag remapping of [nextjs] and [next] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

